# Importing CSV data into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have a CSV file which contains data seperated with tabs. I need to import the data into a MySQL table which consists of two columns. The first CSV column should go into the first column of the table and similarly for the second.

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("translation",$con); 
$open=fopen("EH_excel.txt","r"); 
while(($get=fgetcsv($open,1000,","))!==false) { 
  mysql_query("insert into   dictionary(english,croatian)     
  values('".$get[0]."','".$get[1]."')"); 
} 
fclose($open); echo "Import Done."; 
?>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Here my coding <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("translation",$con);
$open=fopen("EH_excel.csv","r");
while(($get=fgetcsv($open,186096,","))!==false)
{
mysql_query("insert into dictionary(english,croatian)values('".$get[0]."','".$get[1]."')");
}
fclose($open);
echo "Import Done.";
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you have is called `Tab Delimited Files`

This is the way you import it to

SQL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sample.txt' INTO TABLE sample 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' 
ESCAPED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: hi can you tell me where I have keep my file.Inside of www folder?

Comment: It does not matter .. Just add the full path ... and make sure you have acess to read form that location